# delete tr element in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table of tr elements in which i click on an delete for each row, it deletes itself from the table. my html is as below

```
<tr class="tr_body">
    <td>
    <input type="text" class="fabric_input createWOBlockBG small ui-autocomplete-input" name="basefabrics[]" onfocus ="loadUniqueAjax(' . "'fabric_input'" . ')" autocomplete="off">
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" class="fac_input createWOBlockBG small ui-autocomplete-input" name="facSnapshots[]" id="facSnapshot" autocomplete="off">
    </td>
    <td>
    <a class ="deleteRow">delete</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and my jquery is as below

```
$('.deleteRow').click(function(){

    var elementDelete = $(this).parent().parent();
    $('#tablelist').remove(elementDelete);

});
```

however it returns a Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'replace'  when i click on the deleteRow anchor tag. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Did you check that your table has the good id `tablelist` ? Moreover, you can directly remove the TR element using `elementDelete.remove()` instead of using the table (Notice that the TR is not a direct child of your table, because you may forgot the TBODY element between them).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Working example on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ukifin).

```
$('.deleteRow').click(function() {
  $(this).closest("tr")
         .remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ekumuy/1)**

```
$(function(){
  $('.deleteRow').click(function(e){
    $(e.target).closest( 'tr' ).remove();
    //or
    //$(this).closest( 'tr' ).remove();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the element itself

Replace

```
$('#tablelist').remove(elementDelete);
```

with

```
elementDelete.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this function,

```
function removeTableRow(trId) {
$(document.getElementById(trId)).remove();
}
```

and call this function by,

```
removeTableRow( "tr_body" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do something like this

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
    $( '#tablelist .deleteRow' ).click( function ( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $( this ).closest( 'tr' ).remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.deleteRow').click(function(){
    var elementDelete = $(this).parent().parent();

    $(elementDelete).remove();

});
```

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p3Wrj/

Refer http://api.jquery.com/remove/

for proper syntax

Answer (score 0):

Simply use :-

```
$('.deleteRow').click(function(){
 $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Actually you are trying to use the remove as Native javaScript style but in jquery you need not to find the parent element. Jquery will do that on behalf of you, so you just need to specify the element which you want to  remove.

```
ParentElement.remove(childElement); //Javascript style

$(childElement).remove(); // Jquery
```