# How to delete <tr> element in JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I don't know how it's not working. This code from my MVC project. I want to create new folder by using ajax (this case is ok), and delete folder by using ajax, too (this case is not working). Please help me.

I have consulted:
[Delete <tr> using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329205/delete-tr-using-jquery)
[delete tr element in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806557/delete-tr-element-in-jquery)

This is my code:

```
<table class="mdc-data-table__table tableFixHead" id="tblFolder" aria-label="Dessert calories">
                        <thead class="text-center">
                            <tr class="mdc-data-table__header-row text-center">
                                <th class="mdc-data-table__header-cell" style="z-index:100; " role="columnheader" scope="col">Edit</th>
                                <th class="mdc-data-table__header-cell" style="z-index:99;" role="columnheader" scope="col">Folder Name</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody class="mdc-data-table__content text-center" id="tblFolder">
                            @foreach (var directoryName in Model.directNamesList)
                            {
                                <tr class="mdc-data-table__row">
                                    <th class="td-actions text-center" style="z-index:2;">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" name="btnDeletefolder" onclick="service.removeRow(this);" id="@directoryName.ID" class="removeLink btn btn-danger btn-link btn-sm" style="padding:5px;">
                                            <i class="material-icons">close</i>
                                            <div class="ripple-container"></div>
                                        </a>
                                    </th>
                                    <td class="mdc-data-table__cell" style="z-index:1">
                                        <label>@directoryName.FolderName</label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

And this is my script

```
                    <script>
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            $("a.removeLink").on("click", function () {
                                var id = $(this).attr('id').valueOf();
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: '/Admin/HRMAdmin/HRMDeleteFolder?ID=' + id,
                                    type: 'GET',
                                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                    success: function (data) {
                                        //var trow = $(this).closest("tr");
                                        //trow.remove();

                                        var service = {
                                            removeRow: function (el) {
                                                $(el).closest('tr').remove();
                                            }
                                        }
                                        alert(data);
                                    },
                                    error: function (data) {
                                        alert(data);
                                    }
                                })
                            });
                        })
                    </script>
```

This is my script, automatic create row when I add new folder

```
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#btnnewfoldersubmit").on("click", function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/Admin/HRMAdmin/HRMAddNewFolder?Foldername=' + $("#txtFolderName").val(),
                            type: 'GET',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            success: function (data) {
                                alert("Create Success !!!");
                                var tbl = $("#tblFolder");
                                var folder = $("#txtFolderName").val();
                                tbl.append($('<tr class="mdc-data-table__row"> <th class="td-actions text-center" style="z-index:2;">' +
                                    '<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="' + data + '" name="btnDeletefolder" onclick="service.removeRow(this);" class="removeLink btn btn-danger btn-link btn-sm" style="padding:5px;">' +
                                    '<i class="material-icons">close</i>' +
                                    '<div class="ripple-container"></div>' +
                                    '</a > </th >' + '<td class="mdc-data-table__cell" style="z-index:1"> <label>' + folder + '</label> </td> </tr>'));
                            },
                            error: function (data) {
                                alert(data);
                            }
                        });
                    });

                });
            </script>
```

Comment: what error do you get when you try to delete it ? is the ajax successfully executes ?

Comment: Put `var trow = $(this);` outside ajax call and then use `trow.closest("tr").remove()` inside success function.Also , no need to have `onclick="service.removeRow(this);"..` this if your are removing like above.

Comment: Yes, ajax success, I catch by "alert", but "trow" do not work.

Comment: Okay cool. Have your tried what @ swati suggested ?

Comment: I tried, it's still do no work. I dont know how, but I catch every single row in script, alert success.

Comment: So you want to delete the row (tr) when you click on delete `button` ? Is your delete button getting called at all ?

Comment: And when debug, I found one more issue, I can not click on new row I created by jquery, other row is ok (with the same element, same properties).

Comment: No, my delete button just call exactly elementID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues in your `code` you are trying to remove the `tr` in your `success` function but in the success `$(this)` refers to the actual `success` function.

You need to make sure your clicked `removeLink` element is a global `variable` so that it can accessed in your `success` function. like => `var $this = $(this)`

In success we will use it like this:

```
$this.closest("tr").remove()
```

Also, you are adding row dynamically via your ajax success in your table so in this you need to what called is [event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to make sure your the elements are getting `called` after they are appended in the DOM.

Also, as said in the comments you do not need to use `onclick="service.removeRow(this);"..` in your HTML - you can remove this as well.

Replace your `ajax` request to this and it should work fine:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", 'a.removeLink' ,function() {
    //get id
    var id = $(this).attr('id').valueOf();
    //store $(this) as a variable
    var $this = $(this)
    //Ajax
    $.ajax({
      url: '/Admin/HRMAdmin/HRMDeleteFolder?ID=' + id,
      type: 'GET',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      success: function(data) { 
        //remove the clicked row on success
        $this.closest("tr").remove()
      },
      error: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      }
    })
  });
})
```

Comment: When debug, I found another issue. When I created new folder (by last script on fist post), I can not click on new row I created by jquery, other row is ok (with the same element, same properties).

Comment: @DuyKhương You mean you can not click on delete button ? Are you sure you have removed `onclick="service.removeRow(this);"` in your create folder append on success function ?

Comment: Yes, I removed this "onclick".  This new issue from "btnnewfoldersubmit" (the third code), I success when add new folder with delete button. But I can not click on this new button, another button is ok.

Comment: @DuyKhương is the `add (#btnnewfoldersubmit)` button added dynamically as well on each folder ajax success ? or the add button is always on the page